# Why is 'curve' so different from 'lines' and 'points' in R?

Tags: r, plot, lines, points, curve

I would like to fit the frequency data with discrete generalized beta distribution ([DGBD](http://www.plosone.org/article/info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0004791)).

The data look like this:

```
freq = c(1116, 2067, 137 ,  124, 643,  2042, 55  ,47186,  7504, 1488, 211,   1608,   
         3517 , 7  , 896  ,  378, 17 ,3098, 164977  ,  601 ,  196, 637, 149 , 44,2 ,  1801, 882   , 636,5184,  1851,  776 ,   343   , 851, 33  ,4011,   209,  715 , 
         937 , 20,   6922, 2028 , 23,  3045 , 16 , 334,  31 ,  2)

Rank = rank(-freq, ties.method = c("first") )
p = freq/sum(freq)
```

## get the log forms

```
log.f = log(freq)
log.p = log(p)
log.rank = log(Rank)
log.inverse.rank = log(length(Rank)+1-Rank)
```

## linear regression of the discrete generalized beta distribution

```
co=coef(lm(log.p~log.inverse.rank + log.rank))
zmf = function(x) exp(co[[1]]+ co[[2]]*log(length(x)+1-x) + co[[3]]*log(x))
```

## plot

```
plot(p~Rank, xlim = c(1, 80), log = "xy",xlab = "Rank (log)", ylab = "Probability (log)")
curve(zmf, col="blue", add = T)
xx=c(1:length(Rank))
lines(zmf(xx)~xx, col = "red")
points(zmf(xx)~xx, col = "purple")
```

[image]

#### Figure 1. the plot looks like this

#### My question is what is the right way to demonstrate the result? lines (points) or curve?

## Update:

Although I have not figured out the underling logic, the solution is found:

@Frank reminds me to notice the trick of setting the length of n in the curve. It solves the problem. Thus, n in curve is necessary when we try to fit the raw data. Although in many situations, n is ignored.

```
plot(p~Rank, log = "xy",xlab = "Rank (log)", ylab = "Probability (log)")
curve(zmf, col="blue", add = T, n = length(Rank)) # set the the number of x values at which to evaluate.
```

[image]

#### Figure 2 The right way to use curve: specify the 'n'

Comment: looks the same to me just untransformed. the other two are fit to data

Comment: Could you elaborate more? What is the difference?

Comment: well `zmf` is just a generic function, like the formula for a line `y = mx + b` or a `y = x**2` They have generic forms which we can plot, but if you fit them with data or set some parameters (y-intercept, slope, etc), that will change the shape and location of the curve

Comment: @rawr But it's the same function being used in `lines` and `points`.

Comment: @FrankWANG Note that the `log = "xy"` argument to `curve` is ignored  because `add = TRUE`.  Logarithms are applied without the argument as a result of the preceding `plot` command.  This does not explain the difference.  It appears that the answer to the question in bold, is that `lines` and `points` are correct, but something is wrong here with `curve`.  The more interesting question is, what is wrong?

Comment: Exactly. I also find this. I agree with your point: there is something we do not know about curve.

Comment: I don't have much to add by way of explanation, but check out what happens when you add `n=length(Rank)` to your call to `curve`.  Seems to be a more correct line.

Comment: @Frank Same if you specify `xlim = range(Rank)` in the `plot` command, rather than `c(1,80)`

Comment: Still looks like it might be a bug in `curve`.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg When I specify `xlim = range(Rank)` in the `plot` command but not `n=length(Rank)` in the `curve` command, I still get the weird behavior.  Is that not the case for you?

Comment: @Frank It is not.  I get a correct graph.  I'm using 3.0.2 on Linux.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I get the weird graph using 3.0.1 and 3.0.3 on Windows.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg nope no bug but a tricky function definition :) See answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you need to specify the `n` here is because your function depends on `length(x)`!

```
zmf = function(x) exp(co[[1]]+ co[[2]]*log(length(x)+1-x) + co[[3]]*log(x))
                                           ^^^^^^^^^
```

Here the length of the `x`'s provided to your function by `curve` is `n`!

Here is your plot if you stick with the default `n=101` but feed your `line` and `points` with a vector `xx` of length 101:

```
plot(p~Rank, xlim = c(1,80), log = "xy",xlab = "Rank (log)", ylab = "Probability (log)")
curve(zmf, col="blue", add = T)
xx=seq(1,length(Rank),length.out=101)
lines(zmf(xx)~xx, col = "red")
points(zmf(xx)~xx, col = "purple")
```

[image]

Neither voodoo nor bug ! :)